# Mostrar dos datos de una misma tabla en diferentes INPUT

Tags: php, mysql

Poseo una tabla **ARTICULOS** que tiene dos campos:
el primero **Articulo** (numero entero) 
el segundo **Descripcion** (varchar)

En mi sistema muestro un select con todos los registros de la tabla **ARTICULO**
Al seleccionarlo **quisiera** que:

Un textbox que tengo mostrara la **descripcion** del articulo, contenida en la tabla **ARTICULOS**

Esta tabla ya se encuentra con registros.

Este es mi codigo

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
global $cone;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align ="center">Bienvenido</h1>
<a href ="index.html"><ol>Pagina Principal</ol></a>
<a href ="registrar.php"><ol>Registrar</ol></a>
<a href ="listado.php"><ol>Listado</ol></a>
<a href ="Sancion.php"><ol>Sancion</ol></a>
<form method="POST" action ="procesar4.php">     
    <label> Ingrese cedula del sancionado</label>
    <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula1"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese cedula del sancionador</label>
    <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula2"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese tipo de sancion </label>
    <div><select name="sancion">
<?php
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from sanciones");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
echo "<option value='$reg[id_sancion]'>"."$reg[sancion]"."<br/>"."</option>";
}
?>
</select></div>
<label> Ingrese articulo inflingido </label>
<div><select name="articulo" id="articulo">
 <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
        $('#articulo').change(function(e) {

          $('#descripcion').val($(this).val());
        });
      });

</script>


<?php
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from articulos");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
echo "<option value='$reg[id_articulo]'>"."$reg[articulo]"."</option>";

}
$sql =mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT des_articulo 
FROM articulos 
WHERE id_articulo=id_articulo");
$sql2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo "<br/>"."<input type='text' id='descripcion' readonly value='$sql2[des_articulo]'>";

?>

</select></div>  


 <fieldset>
        <legend>Ingrese estado de sancion</legend>


<?php

global $cone;
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from estado_sanciones");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
   echo "<label>";
   echo '<input type="radio" name="estado" value="'.$reg["estado_id"].'">'.$reg["estado"];
echo "</label>";
   }
?>
 </fieldset>
<br/>

<label> Ingrese Fecha inicial de la sancion</label>
  <div> 
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#fecha1" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

<input type="text" name="fecha1" id="fecha1"></p>
 </div>

   <label> Ingrese Fecha Final de la sancion</label>
<div> 
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#fecha2" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
  <input type="text" name="fecha2" id="fecha2"></p>
 </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">

     <label> Ingrese observacion </label>
    <input type="text" id="observacion" name="observacion"><br/>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Existe algún problema con mi respuesta?

Comment: pense que se habia publicado el comentario, lo que me pasaste funciona bien, en el sentido que que crea los textarea con el contenido de cada uno de los valores que corresponden a cada articulo, pero cuando cambio de valor en el select, no se muestran en el textbox.

es asi de complicado hacer algo que parece tan sencillo?

cambiar un select y que muestre a un lado un dato de la misma tabla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código puedo ver errores, como por ejemplo:

- Dentro del `<select id="articulo"`:

  - Tienes un tag `<script>`
  - Imprimes un tag `<input id='descripcion'`
- La consulta para obtener la *descripcion del articulo* le esta faltando que le pases el `id` (eg: `SELECT des_articulo FROM articulos WHERE id_articulo=id_articulo`, esto esta mal)
- Tu `script` para obtener la "*descripción del articulo*" seleccionado en el `<select id="articulo"` es erroneo (eg: `$('#descripcion').val($(this).val());`, esta mal).

Solución:

- Sacar del tag `<select id="articulo"` lo que no va.
- Crear una variable, por ejemplo, `$descripciones` para guardar las descripciones.
- Dentro del `while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {` agregar a la variables `$descripciones` un tag, con `id` único y con estilo oculto, donde guardaremos las descripción del articulo (eg: `des_articulo`)
- Imprimir el valor de la variable `$descripciones`, por fuera del `select`
- Modificar el `script` para que en el `change` del `select` busque la descripción dentro del tag con `id` único.

Así por ejemplo:

```html
<?php
include "conexion.php";
global $cone;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 align ="center">Bienvenido</h1>
  <a href ="index.html"><ol>Pagina Principal</ol></a>
  <a href ="registrar.php"><ol>Registrar</ol></a>
  <a href ="listado.php"><ol>Listado</ol></a>
  <a href ="Sancion.php"><ol>Sancion</ol></a>
  <form method="POST" action ="procesar4.php">
    <label> Ingrese cedula del sancionado</label>
    <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula1"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese cedula del sancionador</label>
    <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula2"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese tipo de sancion </label>
    <div>
      <select name="sancion">
<?php
  $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "select * from sanciones");
  while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
      echo "<option value='$reg[id_sancion]'>" . "$reg[sancion]" . "<br/>" . "</option>";
  }
?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <label> Ingrese articulo inflingido </label>
    <div>
      <select name="articulo" id="articulo">
        <option>Seleccione un articulo</option>
<?php
      $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM articulos");
      $descripciones = '';
      while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
          echo "<option value='$reg[id_articulo]'>" . $reg['articulo'] . "</option>";
          $descripciones .= "<textarea id='desc".$reg['id_articulo']."' style='display: none;'>".$reg['des_articulo']."</textarea>";
      }
?>
      </select>
<?php
      echo $descripciones;
?>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type='text' id='descripcion' readonly placeholder="Seleccione un articulo" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
      $('#articulo').change(function(e) {
        $('#descripcion').val($('#desc' + this.value).val());
      }).trigger('change');
    });
    </script>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Ingrese estado de sancion</legend>
<?php
  $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "select * from estado_sanciones");
  while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
      echo "<label>";
      echo '<input type="radio" name="estado" value="' . $reg["estado_id"] . '">' . $reg["estado"];
      echo "</label>";
  }
?>
 </fieldset>
  <br/>

  <label> Ingrese Fecha inicial de la sancion</label>
    <div>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#fecha1" ).datepicker();
      } );
      </script>
      <input type="text" name="fecha1" id="fecha1"></p>
    </div>
    <label> Ingrese Fecha Final de la sancion</label>
    <div>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#fecha2" ).datepicker();
      } );
      </script>
      <input type="text" name="fecha2" id="fecha2"></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">

    <label> Ingrese observacion </label>
    <input type="text" id="observacion" name="observacion"><br/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pense que se habia publicado el comentario, lo que me pasaste funciona bien, en el sentido que que crea los textarea con el contenido de cada uno de los valores que corresponden a cada articulo, pero cuando cambio de valor en el select, no se muestran en el textbox. es asi de complicado hacer algo que parece tan sencillo? cambiar un select y que muestre a un lado un dato de la misma tabla?

Comment: Sonora raro, pero te amo jajajaja, muchas gracias funciono perfectamente, ya note el error , faltaba el # para que reconociera que era el ID del campo de texto, ahora una duda, si cambio el input type text, por un textarea se mostraria el cuadro grande? para que se muestre todo el text completo.

Ya entendi el significado del punto es para concatenar los while

Comment: Genial, la ultima duda, porque se que esto no se puede publicar, como podria hacer para mostrar nomas cargue la pagina el textarea lleno, que salga por ejemplo 000(Select) Seleccione un articulo(Textbox), ya que quisiera agregar eso. ya coloque ese valor en la base de datos, y pienso evitar que ese este seleccionado usando script

Comment: @VictorA, he actualizado mi respuesta. Mi consejo es no crees dicho valor en la `db`. Para agregarlo al `select`, pudes hacerlo sin `PHP` y en el `input` usaria el atributo `placeholder` para mostrar un texto por defecto.

Comment: doblemente excelente :)

Comment: Marcos que tal? Seria posible que revisaras la nueva pregunta que hice?, pues quiero hacer algo parecido a este código que me hiciste, pero esta vez para mostrar otro selecto con mas datos basados en el id que este presente en el primer select