# Mostrar registros en un select basandose en id de otro select

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un sistema para sancionar a personal administrativo.

hace poco solucione el problema de que al cambiar un select llamado **articulo** se cambiara la descripción en un textarea.

Ahora tengo la siguiente duda:

Yo le agregue al sistema la posibilidad de mostrar los apartados que tienen algunos artículos, pues puede ocurrir que la persona inflija el articulo 105, pero el literal 2.

Entonces agregue ese valor en la base de datos y otra tabla llamada **articulos_apartados**.

Hasta ahora el sistema hace lo siguiente:

1. Muestra el select con todos los articulos
2. Al cambiar el select se muestra la descripcion de dicho articulo en una textarea
3. Automaticamente en otro select, se selecciona el apartado
   correspondiente al articulo

**EL PROBLEMA:**

> en el select me aparecen TODOS los valores, sin importar que estos pertenezcan o no al articulo que fue seleccionado.

**En conclusión QUIERO QUE:**

> Al cambiar el articulo se siga mostrando su descripción pero en el select **apartado** se muestren los literales o valores que contiene el **apartado** y que corresponden a dicho **articulo** y al ser seleccionados aparezca su descripción.
>   Aquí enlace a explicación del script:

[Mostrar dos datos de una misma tabla en diferentes INPUT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44836/mostrar-dos-datos-de-una-misma-tabla-en-diferentes-input)

**---Aqui los codigos---**
**Tabla ARTICULOS:**

```
id_articulo: entero primary key
articulo: entero numero de articulo
des_articulo: descripcion del articulo
```

**Tabla ARTICULOS_APARTADOS:**

```
id_articulo_apartados: entero, primary key
id_articulo_a: entero, este es la llave foranea del articulo
articulo_apartado: entero, numero del literal que corresponde al articulo
descripcion_apartado: describe el apartado
```

**Sancion.PHP**

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Listado del personal sancionado</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null){
    print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='login.php';</script>";
}
?>
<?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<h1>Generar una Sanción<br></h1>

SANCION.PHP

    <?php
    include "conexion.php";
    global $cone;
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

        <title> </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('#cedula1').blur(function(){

            $('#info1').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" />').fadeOut(1000);

            var cedula1 = $(this).val();        
            var dataString = 'cedula1='+cedula1;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "comprobar_disponibilidad1.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#info1').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                }
            });
        });              
    });    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('#cedula2').blur(function(){

            $('#info2').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" />').fadeOut(1000);

            var cedula2 = $(this).val();        
            var dataString = 'cedula2='+cedula2;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "comprobar_disponibilidad2.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#info2').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                }
            });
        });              
    });    
    </script>





      <form method="POST" name="sancion" action ="procesar4.php">
       <div>
       <label> Ingrese cedula del sancionado</label>
        <input type="text" id="cedula1" name="cedula1"><br/>
    <div id="info1"></div>
        </div>


        <div>
        <label> Ingrese cedula del sancionador</label>
        <input type="text" id="cedula2" name="cedula2"><br/>
    <div id="info2"></div>
        </div>


        <label> Ingrese tipo de sancion </label>
        <div>
          <select name="sancion">
    <?php
      $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "select * from sanciones");
      while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
          echo "<option value='$reg[id_sancion]'>" . "$reg[sancion]" . "<br/>" . "</option>";
      }
    ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <label> Ingrese articulo inflingido </label>
        <div>
          <select name="articulo" id="articulo">
            <option value="0">Seleccione un articulo</option>
    <?php
          $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM articulos");

          $descripciones = '';
          while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
              echo "<option value='$reg[id_articulo]'>" . $reg['articulo'] . "</option>";
              $descripciones .= "<textarea id='desc".$reg['id_articulo']."' style='display: none;'>".$reg['des_articulo']."</textarea>";
          }
    ?>
          </select>


               </select>
        </div>
        <label> Ingrese apartado </label>
        <div>
          <select name="apartado" id="apartado">
            <option value="0">Seleccione un apartado</option>
    <?php
        $id_articulo=$_REQUEST["id_articulo"];
        echo $id_articulo;

          $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM articulos_apartados");
           $descripciones_apartado = '';
            while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
              echo "<option value='$reg[id_articulo_a]'>" . $reg['articulo_apartado'] . "</option>";
              $descripciones .= "<textarea id='desc_apartado".$reg['id_articulo_a']."' style='display: none;'>".$reg['descripcion_apartado']."</textarea>";
          }
    ?>
          </select>
    <?php
          echo $descripciones;
    ?>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <textarea  id='descripcion' readonly placeholder="Seleccione un articulo" /></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
          $('#articulo').change(function(e) {
            $('#descripcion').val($('#desc' + this.value).val());
          }).trigger('change');
        });
        </script>

        <?php
          echo $descripciones_apartado;
    ?>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <textarea  id='descripcion_apartado' readonly placeholder="Seleccione un apartado" /></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
          $('#articulo').change(function(e) {
            $('#descripcion_apartado').val($('#desc_apartado' + this.value).val());
          }).trigger('change');
        });
        </script>





        <fieldset>
          <legend>Ingrese estado de sancion</legend>
    <?php
      $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "select * from estado_sanciones");
      while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
          echo "<label>";
          echo '<input type="radio" name="estado" value="' . $reg["estado_id"] . '">' . $reg["estado"];
          echo "</label>";
      }
    ?>
     </fieldset>
      <br/>

      <label> Ingrese Fecha inicial de la sancion</label>
        <div>
          <script>
          $( function() {
            $( "#fecha1" ).datepicker();
          } );
          </script>
          <input type="text" name="fecha1" id="fecha1"></p>
        </div>
        <label> Ingrese Fecha Final de la sancion</label>
        <div>
          <script>
          $( function() {
            $( "#fecha2" ).datepicker();
          } );
          </script>
          <input type="text" name="fecha2" id="fecha2"></p>
        </div>


        <label> Ingrese observacion </label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="observacion" name="observacion"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
      </form>
      <script src="javascript/valida_sancion.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Ejemplo:**

Base de datos(Articulos):

```
id_articulo:1, 
articulo: 101, 
desc_articulo:Molestar las instalaciones,
```

Base de datos(Articulo_apartado)

```
id_articulo_a:1 
articulo_apartado 1: estando en horario de trabajo

id_articulo_a:1 
articulo_apartado 2: estando en horario de descanso

id_articulo_a:1 
articulo_apartado 3: estando sin trabajar.

Ingrese articulo: 101(select) 1,2,3(select)

MUCHAS GRACIAS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He visto en tu código algún pequeño error, no has concatenado bien tus `options` y alguna comilla simple.

Tu código:

```
echo "<option value='$reg[id_articulo_a]'>" . $reg['articulo_apartado'] . "</option>";
                  ^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Actualizado:

```
echo "<option value='".$reg['id_articulo_a']."'>" . $reg['articulo_apartado'] . "</option>";
```

> **Nota:** revisa tu código, que hay unos cuantos mal concatenado, simplemente he puesto uno como ejemplo.

Ahora veamos tu pregunta, como podríamos mostrar nuestra `option` según el articulo seleccionado en otro `select`. Voy hacer un formulario simple, con dichos datos, también he modificado tu `action`, la vamos a mandar vía `AJAX`, para ello cambiamos el botón de envió por un `button` y eliminas el atributo `action` y añadimos un identificador `ID` a nuestro formulario.

**El ejemplo podría quedar de la siguiente manera:**

sancion.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- libreria jQuery -->

  <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){

      //Modificamos option de nuestro 'SELECT'
      $("#articulo").change(function(){

          $.ajax({
            url:"cambiar-datos-select.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:"id_select="+$("#articulo").val(),

            success: function(opciones){
              $("#apartado").html(opciones);
            }
          });
      });


      //Formulario procesar4
      $(document).on('submit', '#frm-sancion', function() {

        //Obtenemos datos formulario
        var data = $(this).serialize();  

        $.ajax({            
          type : 'POST',
          url  : 'procesar4.php',
          data : data,
          success :  function(data) { 
            $(".result").html(data); 
          }
        });    

        return false;

      });

    }); //Fin documento
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="frm-sancion" method="POST" name="sancion">
  <label> Ingrese articulo inflingido </label>
  <select name="articulo" id="articulo">
      <option value="0">Seleccione un articulo</option>
      <?php
        //Conexion
        require'conexion.php';

        $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM articulos");

        $descripciones = '';
        while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
          echo "<option value=". $reg['id_articulo'].">"  . $reg['articulo'] . "</option>";          
        }
      ?>
  </select>

  <label>Ingrese apartado</label>
  <select id="apartado" name="apartado"> 
    <option value="0">Seleccione primero un articulo</option> 
  </select>      

  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<div class="result"><!-- Resultado AJAX procesar --></div>

</body>
</html>
```

cambiar-datos-select.php

```
<?php   
    //Si esta definida la variable Ajax y no es NULL.
    if(isset($_POST['id_select'])) { 

        //Conexion
        require'conexion.php';

        //Obtenemos el valor de la variable de Ajax (es decir, el ID).
        $id_select = mysqli_real_escape_string($cone,$_POST['id_select']);      

        //Sentencia -> mostramos resultao segun el 'ID' de nuestro articulo via AJAX.
        $sql = mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM articulos_apartados WHERE id_articulo_a='$id_select'");                                           

        echo "<option value=0>Selecciona tu apartado</option>"; //Si no quieres mostrar este mensaje, podrias quitarla.

        //Comprobamos existencias.
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {

            //Salida data.                          
            while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                //Obtenemos datos asociados desde la Base de datos.
                $id_bd = $reg['id_articulo_a'];
                $artic_apartado = $reg['articulo_apartado'];
                //Option modificado :)              
                echo "<option value='$id_bd'>" . $artic_apartado . "</option>";                                                             
            }
        } mysqli_close($cone);  //Cerramos conexión.   
    }        
?>
```

Te aconsejo a utilizar [sentencias preparadas](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), son muy últiles frente a Inyecciones SQL.