# Usuario entra sin tener contraseña, Error en IF

Tags: php, html

cuando va a validad de que el usuario y la contraseña sean iguales a las necesarias, el usuario puede entrar sin tener la contraseña

**INDEX.PHP**

```
 <html>
    <h1> Hola! Esto es otra practica </h2>
    <body>
    <form action="conectar.php" method="post">
    <label for="pedir"> Usuario </label>
    <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="coloca usuario">
    <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" placeholder="coloca clave">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="loguear">
    </body>
    </html>
```

CONECTAR.PHP

```
    <?php

$usuario=$_REQUEST["usuario"];
$contraseña=$_REQUEST["contraseña"];

if (!isset($usuario) && !isset($contraseña))
{
}
else if ($usuario =="user" && $contraseña=="pass")
{
echo "bienvenido";
} 
else 
{
echo "CHAO";
}
?>
```

VERSION FINAL:

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Hola! Esto es otra practica </h1>
<form action="conectar.php" method="post">
<label for="usuario"> Usuario </label>
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="coloca usuario">
<input type="password" name="contraseña" id="contraseña" placeholder="coloca clave">
<input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="loguear">
</body>
</html>
```

**CONECTAR.PHP**

```
  <?php
    $usuario=$_POST["usuario"];
    $contraseña=$_POST["contraseña"];
    if (isset($_POST['enviar']))
    {
    if (!isset($usuario) && !isset($contraseña))
    {
    }
    else if ($usuario =="user" && $contraseña=="pass")
    {
    echo "bienvenido";
    } 
    else 
    {
    echo "CHAO";
    }
    }else
    {
    echo "No se ENVUO";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeramente estas recibiendo una variable llamada `clave` y no `contraseña` (por cierto no uses palabras acentuadas para variables).

en tu archivo .php recibirias los valores de `usuario` y `clave`

```
 <?php

$usuario=$_REQUEST["usuario"];
$contraseña=$_REQUEST["clave"];
```

Otro problema es la comparación que es incorrecta es la de la contraseña:

```
else if ($usuario =="user" && $contraseña="pass")
```

deberia ser :

```
else if ($usuario =="user" && $contraseña=="pass")
```

---

En realidad tienes varios errores, pero para solucionar 
te recomiendo usar el mismo archivo INDEX.PHP pero modificar tu archivo CONECTAR.PHP a:

```
    <?php

$usuario=$_REQUEST["usuario"];
$clave=$_REQUEST["clave"];

if (!isset($usuario) && !isset($clave))
{
}
else if ($usuario =="user" && $clave=="pass")
{
echo "bienvenido";
} 
else 
{
echo "CHAO";
}
?>
```

Comment: creo que te equivocaste en redactar `else if ($usuario =="user" && $contraseña="pass")
deberia ser :

else if ($usuario =="user" && $contraseña=="pass")`

Comment: @x-rw No se ha equivocado, simplemente ha puesto un ejemplo "mal hecho" y después lo ha corregido diciendo la manera correcta es .....

Comment: Cierto no leí muy bien parecía igual pero se diferencian en el =,disculpas

Answer (score 2):

A la respuesta acertada de @Jorgesys añado algunos detalles básicos, por que creo que es una situación que se repite con bastante frecuencia cuando se inician en programación de formularios y surgen muchas dudas al respecto. Así servirá para futuros visitantes.

> 1.- Activar el reporte de errores

En modo desarrollo o pruebas o ejercicio (como queramos llamarlo) es recomendable usar el reporte de errores de `php`. Nos da una pista (no siempre) de que y/o donde está ocurriendo el error.

En el inicio del archivo `php`:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'html_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'display_startup_errors', 1 );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
```

> 2.- Los datos que recibes

Si el formulario envía los datos mediante `POST`, lo ideal sería recibirlos por el mismo medio.

Suponiendo que `localhost` es el `host` que aloja el formulario y la validación, esto daría positivo:

```
localhost/conectar.php?usuario=user&clave=pass
```

Se soluciona cambiando:

```
$usuario = $_REQUEST["usuario"];
$clave   = $_REQUEST["clave"];
```

Por:

```
$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$clave   = $_POST["clave"];
```

> 3.- Condicionales y su lógica

Algunos condicionales puede no dar el resultado esperado ([Operadores Lógicos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php)).

El primero que pones a prueba es: `if( !isset( $usuario ) && !isset( $clave ) )`

Quiere decir que las dos comparaciones deben ser positivas para obtener un positivo. ¿Pero que ocurre si nos encontramos este caso?

```
<!-- Usuario definido incorrectamente -->
<input type="text" name="usuarioXXXX" id="usuario" placeholder="coloca usuario">
<input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" placeholder="coloca clave">
```

La lógica nos diría que al no estar definido **uno** de los campos del formulario, debería dar positivo el primer `if`, en cambio, caso uno, da error por no estar definida la variable correctamente, o dos, en caso de no lanzar errores o suprimirlos, no obtenemos el resultado esperado.

Algunas de las soluciones básicas para el caso dado:

```
// true si uno de los dos es true
if( !isset( $usuario ) || !isset( $clave ) ) {
    echo "Formulario no válido";
} else{
    //...
}
```

Hacer la validación de definición antes de comparar los valores insertados.
Puedes encontrar más información en el primer tercio de la página de `php` [Operador Ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
// En caso de no estar definida se le asigna un string sin carácteres
// 1.- Evita errores
// 2.- Las claves no podrán coincidir
$usuario = ( isset( $_POST["usuario"] ) ) ? $_POST["usuario"] : '';
$clave   = ( isset( $_POST["clave"] ) ) ? $_POST["clave"] : '';

if( $usuario == "user" && $clave == "pass" ) {
    echo "Bienvenido";
}
else {
    echo "CHAO";
}
```

> 4.- Errores en el `Html`

```
<h1> Hola! Esto es otra practica </h2>
```

Cuando debería de ser:

```
<h1> Hola! Esto es otra practica </h1>
```

Y además estar dentro de las etiquetas `<body></body>`

El `label` no coincide con el `input`

```
<label for="pedir"> Usuario </label>
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="coloca usuario">
```

La corrección:

```
<label for="usuario"> Usuario </label>
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="coloca usuario">
```

Espero sea de ayuda,

*Lecturas adicionales*
*Buscar información sobre validaciones de datos de entrada en formularios*
*Buscar información concreta sobre validaciones para XSS*
*Buscar información sobre protección CSRF*

PD.: Si encuentran errores en la redacción comenten y edito.

Comment: Yo no comprobaría si están puestas las variables usuario o clave... comprobaría si el formulario fue enviado... es decir: `if (isset($_POST['enviar']) { ... })`... he hecho una pregunta sobre eso [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32133/como-y-cuando-se-usan-isset-y-empty-correctamente)

Comment: Gracias por comentar @aldanux. La lógica para procesar un formulario depende de muchos factores. Me he ceñido al ejemplo inicial, sin grandes variaciones del código original. Lo que comentas es cierto, y más bien por lo general lo que se comprueba primero es si `POST` está definido, después si el contenido es válido, y todas las validaciones necesarias antes de pasar a comprobar las credenciales, identificación, bloqueos por intentos repetidos, csrf, reputación ip, localización geográfica... por hacer validaciones que no sea ;-)

Comment: gracias por las correciones buscara lo que me has comentado. una de las cosas que me habian sugerido otros amigos era usar esto que comentas: "$usuario = ( isset( $_POST["usuario"] ) ) ? $_POST["usuario"] : '';
$clave   = ( isset( $_POST["clave"] ) ) ? $_POST["clave"] : '';" lo habia realizado pero tenia el error del =

Comment: @aldanux ya lei tu pregunta, entonces para que el codigo quede bien o mejor formulado deberia aplicar todo lo que explican en tu pregunta o como esta el mio (luego de la correcion de Jorgesys) esta bien?

Comment: Por otra parte, me ayudarian con esta duda: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47066/mostrar-literales-de-un-articulo-previamente-seleccionado

Comment: @VictorA. - Te dejo [aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/915369a5725bdae844a9c23aad2cbf04384aab57) unos ejemplos... El primer ejemplo sería como la tienes ahora pero en vez de usar `isset()` usaria `empty()`, porque isset al estar la variable vacía te da `true` igual... el segundo ejemplo he recortado un poco el código... puedes meter la primera condición y la segunda en una... saludos

Comment: @aldanux @VictorA. El problema común de usar `empty` es que tenemos que tener muy muy claro que resultado arroja, si no, podemos encontrarnos con comportamientos no deseados. Ejemplo, usarlo con un campo de formulario opcional... `empty('')` daría `true` o con un campo de tipo _cantidad_ y elijo o escribo "0", `empty('0')` daría `true` a pesar de que el contenido es una las opciones válidas.

Comment: Por eso mismo he dejado el link...en el primer comentario... donde está todo mencionado... ademas el primer ejemplo que haz mencionado ahora `empty('')` si no seria `true` seria un `bug` de escandalo

Comment: @aldanux, el ejemplo no va por ahí... igual me expliqué mal, el ejemplo va de que un campo de formulario opcional, se puede enviar _vacío_ y sería válido, pero la validación con `empty('')` lo daría como *no válido*. Es bastante más restrictivo que `isset` en estos casos. Solo era un comentario de una situación probable a tener en cuenta. Nada más que eso.

Comment: y si le pones `!` al `empty()` ya seria valido... no? :) Bueno.. lo dicho esta... no podemos extender aquí los comentarios demasiado si no los moderadores nos trasladan a otra dimensión del universo... ;) saludos

Comment: jejejeje gracias :)